# Postfix vs Google SMTP servers inconsistency

Tags: email, postfix, remote, openssl

I wanted to host my own mail server and in order to do so I've installed Postfix 2.7.0 and Dovecot 1.2.9 on Ubuntu Server 10.04. I had fun reading the docs and configuring all these great tools, I am also hosting locally a DNS server and a Web server but right now I am stuck on something regarding Postfix.

One big problem I face right now is that Google SMTP servers reject my mail **ONLY WHEN** it is being sent remotely. Strange, right?

So if I `telnet localhost 25`, issue `AUTH LOGIN`(not an open relay of course) then send the mail I get a `status = sent` and I **actually receive** the mail message in my Gmail's account Inbox. Works like a charm.

On the other hand, if I want to send the mail from a remote host, I use

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.mydomain.com:465
```

Then I issue `AUTH LOGIN`, the login process is successful. So I don't have a problem communicating with my server. I can see what happens in the log files. But when I try to send mail like this, Google replies with:

> Our system has detected an unusual rate of 421-4.7.0 unsolicited mail
>   originating from your IP address. To protect our 421-4.7.0 users from
>   spam, mail sent from your IP address has been temporarily 421-4.7.0
>   rate limited.

Why Google accepts my mail if being sent locally but rejects it when I `openssl` to my server and send it remotely? It's like Postfix on my server makes Google aware of how the email it forwards got to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The IP of the host `mail.mydomain.com` is sending too many mails, unsolicited emails which is worse, too fast. This is clear from the error message:

> Our system has detected an unusual rate of 421-4.7.0 **unsolicited mail originating from your IP address**. To **protect** our 421-4.7.0 users **from spam**, mail sent from your **IP address has been temporarily 421-4.7.0 rate limited**.

So, investigate if there has been a security breach in your host, or if there are other host that shares your IP which have problems.

Comment: I don't recognise the `421-4.7.0` syntax.

Comment: @FaheemMitha it's possibly an alias for something else

Comment: OK, @Braiam but why it DOES work when I send the mail from localhost, using `telnet localhost 25`? I mean, the IP of the mail server is the same! And Google does not reject it this way.

Comment: The "does work" vs "doesn't work" is probably a red herring.
The 421 syntax comes from line breaks in the SMTP response message protocol.